# Set CSS to text in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to set a different CSS style to certain texts in a JavaScript function.

[image: Desired output example]

For example, set the styles proposed in the image to the attached code.
Some advice?

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var nowDate = new Date();
var countDownDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 15, 30, 0, 0);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  if (hours >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("shipping-countdown").innerHTML = "Order within " + hours + "h " +
      minutes + "m " + seconds + "s " + "to have your order shipped on " // date of shipment;
  } else if (hours < 1 && minutes < 1) {
    document.getElementById("shipping-countdown").innerHTML = "Order within " + seconds + "s " +
      "to have your order shipped on " // date of shipment;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("shipping-countdown").innerHTML = "Order within " + minutes + "m " +
      seconds + "s " + "to have your order shipped on " // date of shipment;
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="shipping-countdown"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a span with CSS class around the output of your time:

like:

```
document.getElementById("shipping-countdown").innerHTML = "Order within <span class='time'>" +  minutes + "m "  + seconds + "s </span>" + "to have your order shipped on ";
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/ron7/pen/oNXKPrg

Answer (score 0):

Hey is this what you're looking for? <s>I'm not sure why the timer is not working as expected, did not go through the timer code too much.</s> But what I did was create 2 spans within the paragraph tag to add the countdown timer and the date. I used the attached css to color the text.

Edit: added a 1.5 hour timer

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var nowDate = new Date();
var countDownDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), nowDate.getHours()+1, nowDate.getMinutes()+30, 0, 0);

console.log(countDownDate);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var date = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();
  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  if (hours >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerText = hours + "h " +
      minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "; 
  } else if (hours < 1 && minutes < 1) {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerText = seconds + "s ";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerText = minutes + "m " +
      seconds + "s "
  }
  datearray = date.split(',');
  document.getElementById("date-holder").innerText = datearray[0];
})
```

```css
#countdown{
  color:green;
}
#date-holder{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="shipping-countdown">Order within <span id="countdown"></span>to have your order shipped on <span id="date-holder"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any element like `p` or `span` or even `h1` etc. only thing what matters is provide a color for the element you choose in the `css`.

I have used `p` as an example and my fellow friends too shared different example. feel free to pick any.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var nowDate = new Date();
var countDownDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 15, 30, 0, 0);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  if (hours >= 1) {
    document.getElementById("shipping-countdown").innerHTML = "Order within <p class='changeColor'>" + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s </p>" + "to have your order shipped on "; // date of shipment
  } else if (hours < 1 && minutes < 1) {
    document.getElementById("shipping-countdown").innerHTML = "Order within <span class='changeColor'> " + seconds + "s </span>" + "to have your order shipped on " // date of shipment;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("shipping-countdown").innerHTML = "Order within <span class='changeColor'> " + minutes + "m " +
      seconds + "s </span>" + "to have your order shipped on " // date of shipment;
  }
});
```

```css
.changeColor {
  color: red;
  /* change the color as you desire */
}
```

```html
<p id="shipping-countdown"></p>
```